# adding another screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

i am currently creating an android app that uses the kivy framework and a package from kivy garden. i want to add another screen in it but i cant. thank you

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ListProperty,ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.metrics import dp
from material.flatui.flatui import FloatingAction,RaisedButton,_MaterialButton
from garden import *
from sqlalchemy import *
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class MyTab(GridLayout, AndroidTabsBase):
    pass

class MyTabb(FloatLayout,AndroidTabsBase):
    thoughts = ObjectProperty()


class MyTabbb(FloatLayout,AndroidTabsBase):
    pass


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager,Screen):
    pass

class ShoppingScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ExampleApp(App):
    thoughts = ObjectProperty()
    def build(self):
        android_tabs = AndroidTabs()
        return android_tabs


if __name__=='__main__':
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
    LabelBase.register(name='Modern Pictograms',
                   fn_regular='modernpics.ttf')
    LabelBase.register(name='Heydings',
                   fn_regular='heydings.ttf')

    LabelBase.register(name='Roboto',
                   fn_regular='Roboto-Thin.ttf')


    Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#008CD4')
    ExampleApp().run()
```

and the code in the kv lang

```
<FBut@Button>:
    font_size: 100
    font_name: 'modernpics'

<AndroidTabs>:
    tab_indicator_height: '2dp'
    anim_threshold: 0
    MyTab:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    cols: 2
    spacing: 5
    text: 'BUDGET'
    FBut:
        text: 'i'
```

so i want to add another screen to enable me view other widgets

Comment: What doesn't work? It seems like your AndroidTabs has one tab, the MyTab. Is that not what you want? Do you want to also add MyTabb and MyTabbb? If so you should add them just like MyTab. Or does MyTab also not appear?

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want a custom ScreenManager to inherit both from ScreenManager and Screen? Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @syntonym the tabs are working perfectly but i want to open another screen when i press a button in the MyTab or MyTabb

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr because this is how i create a screenmanager in almost all the programs i have built using kivy